# React - Value changed after Component Rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, use-effect

I have been working on a food related React Native App and for the login I wanted to seperate the Stacks which are returned for normal Users and Restaurants.

The Problem I am experiencing is that the returned value of `restaurantUserChecker` is different to what the 2nd `UseEffect` gets. `console.log('1', doc.exists)` is true and therefore should return true. But `console.log('2', val)` is false which results in all users getting the same stack.

```
  async function restaurantUserChecker(){
  const check = firestore().collection('restaurantUsers').doc(auth().currentUser.uid); 

    await (check.get()).then((doc) => {
    if (doc.exists) {
      console.log('1', doc.exists);
      return true;
    }
  }).catch((error) => console.log(error));

  return false;
}

  function MyStack() {

  const [restaurantUser, setRestaurantUser] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(auth().currentUser.uid);
    restaurantUserChecker().then((val) => {
      console.log('2', val);
      setRestaurantUser(val);
    }).catch((error) => console.log(error));
  }, []);

  if(restaurantUser){
    return <RestaurantHomeStack/>
  }

  return <DrawerNavigator />;
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <SafeAreaProvider>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <MyStack/>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </SafeAreaProvider>
  );
}
```

I would appreciate all kind of help, as I have struggled for many hours on this problem.

Comment: Your return true is only returning for the function it is in (the `(doc) =>`), not `restaurantUserChecker`.  That value is effectively ignored and `restaurantUserChecker` is always going to return false.

Answer (score 0):

Your function **restaurantUserChecker** must return a Promise.

```
async function restaurantUserChecker() {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        const check = firestore()
        .collection("restaurantUsers")
        .doc(auth().currentUser.uid);

    await check
        .get()
        .then((doc) => {
            if (doc.exists) {
                console.log("1", doc.exists);
                resolve(true);
            }
        })
        .catch((error) =>{ console.log(error); reject(error)});

    resolve(false);
    });
}
```

Comment: Your answer doesn't compile because your promise executor needs to be `async` since you `await check`.  Also, it's not absolutely required to return a promise.

Comment: You are right, I modified the answer with the async keyword, maybe it's not required to return a promise, but in the case of the code above, I think we must return a promise. Your answer is also simple and I think it's easier.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't required to return a promise from `restaurantUserChecker` as the other answer suggests.  It is allowed to call `then` on an `async` function.  The following changes to `restaurantUserChecker` should also perform as you intended.

```
async function restaurantUserChecker(){
  const check = firestore()
        .collection("restaurantUsers")
        .doc(auth().currentUser.uid);

  try {
     var doc = await check.get();
     if (doc.exists) {
        console.log('1', doc.exists);
        return true;
     }
  } catch(error) {
       console.log(error);
  }
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Both of your answers worked and now I understand what caused the issue. You're the heroes we don't deserve but need, if I'm allowed to quote Batman here.
Thanks a lot guys!